# Remove all array elements except what I want?

Tags: php, arrays

I have controller that takes post parameters from HTML form, it will then send them to model that will insert the array into Cassandra database.

It is SQLInjection proof, because it's NoSQL, however what I'm afraid is that user can just simulate 100k post parameters or just add some that I don't need and it will be inserted into database. How can I make sure that only the values I need will stay in my array.

Example:

```
$post = ['parent_id', 'type', 'title', 'body', 'tags']; // Good
$post = ['parent_id', 'type', 'title', 'body', 'tags', 'one', 'two', 'three'] // Bad
```

How do I make sure that my array will unset all the elements that are not in *good* example?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You are looking for [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php):

```
$good = ['parent_id', 'type', 'title', 'body', 'tags'];
$post = ['parent_id', 'type', 'title', 'body', 'tags', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

print_r(array_intersect($good, $post));
```

**[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/KTg08N)**.

Of course this specific example does not make much sense because it works on array *values*, but there is also [`array_intersect_key`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) that does the same based on keys.

Comment: @Qmal: `$good` has good names as *values*, while `$post` has them as *keys*. The simplest fix would be to pass in `array_flip($good)` instead of `$good` so that both inputs have the good names as keys.

Comment: The codepad links in the answer and comments have reverted to the default "hello world" script. :-(

Answer (score 104):

By whitelisting the entries you **do** expect.

```
<?php
$post = array( 
    'parent_id' => 1,
    'type' => 'foo', 
    'title' => 'bar', 
    'body' => 'foo bar', 
    'tags' => 'foo, bar', 
    'one' => 'foo',
    'two' => 'bar',
    'three' => 'qux'
);

$whitelist = array(
    'parent_id',
    'type',
    'title',
    'body',
    'tags'
);

$filtered = array_intersect_key( $post, array_flip( $whitelist ) );

var_dump( $filtered );
```

Anyway, using Cassandra as a data-store is of course not a reason not to do validation on the data you're receiving.

Comment: This page doesn't make a good dupe target because this answer is highly voted, does something different from the accepted answer, and has deviated sample data.  Not good for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

What about multidimensional array? I was researched for a couple of hours for this solution, nowhere found an optimal solution. so, i wrote it by myself

```
function allow_keys($arr, $keys)
    {
        $saved = [];

        foreach ($keys as $key => $value) {
            if (is_int($key) || is_int($value)) {
                $keysKey = $value;
            } else {
                $keysKey = $key;
            }
            if (isset($arr[$keysKey])) {

                $saved[$keysKey] = $arr[$keysKey];
                if (is_array($value)) {

                    $saved[$keysKey] = allow_keys($saved[$keysKey], $keys[$keysKey]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $saved;
    }
```

use: example

```
$array = [
        'key1' => 'kw',
        'loaa'=> ['looo'],
        'k'    => [
            'prope' => [
                'prop'  => ['proo', 'prot', 'loolooo', 'de'],
                'prop2' => ['hun' => 'lu'],
            ],
            'prop1' => [

            ],
        ],
    ];
```

call: example

```
allow_keys($array, ['key1', 'k' => ['prope' => ['prop' => [0, 1], 'prop2']]])
```

output:

```
Array ( [key1] => kw [k] => Array ( [prope] => Array ( [prop] => Array ( [0] => proo [1] => prot ) [prop2] => Array ( [hun] => lu ) ) ) )
```

so you get only needed keys from the multidimensional array. it is not limited only for "multidimensional", you can use it by passing an array like

```
['key1', 'loaa']
```

output you get:

```
Array ( [key1] => kw [loaa] => Array ( [0] => looo ) )
```

cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This is called white listing, your example is misleading as the `$_POST` is an association array.

```
$post = [
    'parent_id' => 'val',
    'type' => 'val',
    'title' => 'val',
    'body' => 'val',
    'tags' => 'val',
    'one' => 'val',
    'two' => 'val',
    'three'=>'val',
];

$whitelist = ['parent_id', 'type', 'title', 'body', 'tags'];

$sanitized_post = array_whitelist_assoc($post, $whitelist);
```

This is a whitelisting function I created for associative arrays.

```
if(!function_exists('array_whitelist_assoc')){

    /**
     * Returns an associative array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all the arguments when using their values as keys.
     *
     * @param array $array The array with master keys to check.
     * @param array $array2 An array to compare keys against its values.
     * @return array $array2,... A variable list of arrays to compare.
     * 
     */

    function array_whitelist_assoc(Array $array1, Array $array2) {

        if(func_num_args() > 2){
            $args = func_get_args();
            array_shift($args);
            $array2 = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $args);
        } 
        return array_intersect_key($array1, array_flip($array2)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Its worth remembering that while `array_intersect` and `array_intersect_key` are good they might well be overkill. In my situation I only wanted 1 element left, therefore the simplest option was just to rebuild the array I wanted based on the key/values I needed. I wonder at what point therefore the array_intersect's don't become worth it and you are simply better off with `$new = array('whatI'=>'want');`. I believe in the OP this is worth it but in smaller cases it might be overkill.

Alternatively in response to the original question simply using `unset` might have been a cheaper option - `unset($post['one'],$post['two'],$post['three'])`. Again though, it relates to the point at which this becomes too inefficient and the array_intersect functions are better.

Comment: Cant believe I didnt think of that lolllllllllllll

Comment: Problem with overkill, u just saved my day, +1

Answer (score 1):

This will output the same as $post_allowed. What it does is only allow the values in $post_input that are also present in $post_allow.

```
$post_allowed = ['parent_id', 'type', 'title', 'body', 'tags'];
$post_input   = ['parent_id', 'type', 'title', 'body', 'tags', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
$post = array_intersect($post_input, $post_allowed);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you’re dealing with associative arrays and you don’t want to use `array_intersect_key()` for any reason, you can also do a simpler approach of manually build a new array using the values you want from the old one.

```
$post = array(
    'parent_id' => 1,
    'type' => "post",
    'title' => "Post title",
    'body' => "Post body",
    'tags' => "Post tags",
    'malicious' => "Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--"
);
$good = array(
    'parent_id' => $post['parent_id'],
    'type' => $post['type'],
    'title' => $post['title'],
    'body' => $post['body'],
    'tags' => $post['tags']
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array intersection. [array intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), it will help you.

Comment: This link-only answer would be better positioned as a comment since it is noticeably less informative compared to other complete answers.