# Fill value into $arrayA, if same key exists in $arrayB

Tags: php

In `php` language, do we have anything handy to do task as the following snippet?

```
$acceptableInputs = [];
foreach ($this->fields as $field) {
    $value = array_key_exists($field, $formInputs)
        ? $formInputs[$field]
        : '';
    $acceptableInputs[$field] = $value;
}
```

Comment: 3 lines are pretty *handy* I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove all array elements except what I want?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122801/remove-all-array-elements-except-what-i-want)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$acceptableInputs = array_intersect_key($formInputs, array_flip($this->fields)) +
                    array_fill_keys($this->fields, null);
```

See http://php.net/array_intersect_key.

Comment: ah.... I see I missed an important feature in my code example... could you please advice if this is still applicable?

Comment: Just add the same fields with default values (here: `null`) to the data. Updated sample.

Comment: I've tried this method and it's about three time faster in execution time, and product almost the same result. Thank you.